# Swagger - Get API showing empty Array on execute

Tags: reactjs, swagger, documentation

I am working on React application. I have dropdown data coming from API. In FrontEnd I consoled and checked its empty object. Then checked in swagger, GET API on execute showing empty. I have many other dropdowns to which data coming from API, other fields i get  but for two fields am not getting. What can be the issue?

Comment: You may  share some code and probably few screenshots of the interface so that people can get a better understanding of the issue. 
Try to elaborate what you really need as much as you can ...